# How to create a table in SQL Server with PRIMARY as the column name?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to migrate table from oracle to SQL Server. While creating a table in SQL Server, I'm facing below issue

```
CREATE TABLE schema.customer
(
    NAME varchar(20),
    PRIMARY varchar(1),
    ADDRESS varchar(20)
);
```

**Error:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line xx
> Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'

Can anyone please help me out in resolving the issue ?

Comment: please do avoid using keyword as column name : `NAME`, `PRIMARY`, `ADDRESS`. Basically those that appear in blue color in `SSMS`

Comment: I'd **rename** that column `PRIMARY` to `IsPrimary` and make it a `BIT` type column ....

Comment: I've never seen a good use case for anything declared as varchar(1). There is nothing variable about these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add square brackets before and after column name, Just like below:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
NAME varchar(20),
[PRIMARY] varchar(1),
ADDRESS varchar(20)
);
```

Because "PRIMARY" is keyword in `SQL Server`.